# ASync TCP Client/Server issue

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, tcp, server

I have this Server method called when client connected:

```
class Server {
    protected override void clientIn(TcpClient client)//Called when a Client comes in
    {
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] y = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        objectState state = new objectState();
        state.buffer = y;
        state.user = client;
        stream.BeginRead(y, 0, y.Length, read, state);
    }

    public void read(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("GetData");
        objectState state = (objectState)ar.AsyncState;
        byte[] buffer = state.buffer;

        TcpClient client = state.user;
        int byte=client.GetStream().EndRead(ar);
        client.GetStream().BeginRead(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize, read, state);

        String text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
        Console.WriteLine(text);

    }       
}

class objectState
{
    public TcpClient user;
    public byte[] buffer;
}
```

I send two data from two different client and my problem is this:

If I don't execute the instruction "Console.WriteLine(text);", in Console I get 2 times the message "GetData"(it means that I get the data from 2 clients),

but If I execute the instruction "Console.WriteLine(text);", in Console I get 1 time the message "GetData" and below the data just got. It's the first client's data and the second client's data was lost but I don't understand why.

Can you help me?

Thank you for your time

UPDATE:

I edited the code in this way and it works fine , but I don't understand why:

```
    protected override void clientIn(TcpClient client) 
            {
                objectState state = new objectState();
                state.user = client;
                state.buffer= new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

                client.Client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(read), state);

            }

public void read(IAsyncResult ar)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("GetData");
            objectState state = (objectState)ar.AsyncState;

            TcpClient client = stato.user;

            int dataSize = client.Client.EndReceive(ar);
            String data = "";

            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0,dataSize);
            Console.WriteLine("\n "+data);

            client.Client.BeginReceive(stato.buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(read), state);
        }
```

I don't understand where was wrong before.

UPDATE 2:

```
 public void read(IAsyncResult ar)
        {


        Console.WriteLine("GetData");
        objectState state = (objectState)ar.AsyncState;
        byte[] buffer = state.buffer;

        TcpClient client = state.user;
        int dataSize=client.GetStream().EndRead(ar);
        String text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
        state.buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];//new buffer
        client.GetStream().BeginRead(state.buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize, read, state);
        Console.WriteLine(text);

       }
```

Comment: I can't help you with your bug, but I noticed that you call `BeginRead` again before processing the stuff that you read. Since you are using only a single state this means your buffer might get corrupted by a subsequent read operation. I would first process the buffer, and then start a new read operation.

Comment: I tried to do like you suggest but the problem remains.

Comment: What do you mean when say "you are using only a single state"?

Comment: You reuse the `state` object for the next `BeginRead`. You might overwrite the `buffer` while calling `ASCII.GetString` on that same buffer for example.

Comment: maybe I bad understand the async Server/Client in C#.NET. I use only state object because I think that the when a client comes in , system execute for each client the method "clientIn" and then I create , for each client, different "objectState" and then for each client begin reading. When a client sends data the system execute the read method and then for that specific client I start again to read data and for this reason in the "read" method when I call "BeginRead" I pass the "objectState" that I get in input by "IAsyncResult", because I think it's related to that specific client.

Comment: I do not know if I was clear. please If I was wrong to  understand something tell me

Comment: I don't know how to put it clearer than that: you call `BeginRead` again before you are done processing the buffer you just got. And `BeginRead` writes the data into the **same buffer object**. You have **only one buffer** but potentially multiple simultaneous read operations that write to that buffer.

Comment: I added new my solution but I don't understand where was wrong before.

Comment: It's just like Dirk already said: in your original code, because you call `BeginReceive()` again before you're done reading the data from the `buffer` object and because you're reusing the same `buffer` object in the new receive, it is possible for the next receive to complete before you are done processing the current receive. And if it completes, it will overwrite the data in the `buffer` object. This even can happen on a single-CPU system if the current thread is pre-empted before finishing with `buffer`, allowing the second receive to complete before the current thread gets to run again.

Comment: @Dirk you might want to post that as the answer.

Comment: I thank you for your patience, but I still do not understand where I use only one buffer. I edited again the code(I added it in the question like "UPDATE 2") but it still doesn't work. you could kindly attach the answer with the code , so why in words I can not understand what I did wrong . Thank you again

Comment: no one can help me ?

Comment: @ramikalli The initial code has the problem of data in a reused buffer being overwritten, "UPDATE" doesn't have this problem and Dirk explained why, and "UPDATE 2 _still_ doesn't work". You should post this as a new question, because the cause of the original problem has been fixed. And as a side effect, your new question will attract new viewers.